# fs.readdir not retrieving files

Tags: javascript, php, file

I want to make a JavaScript code that created dynamically a list of files that I have in a specific folder on my server. This list will be presented when I press a button and each object will have a checkbox. The selected items will then be downloaded with another submit button and I guess some PHP.

So far I used JavaScript code I found online to find the names of the files and then call another function to create the elements but no luck.
It seems that  the function doesn't retrieve any files. Here is my code:

```
function createEl(a){
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("cboxes");
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    checkBox.value = a;
    myDiv.appendChild(checkBox);
    myDiv.appendChild(label);
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));

}
function foldlist(){
const testFolder = './xampp/htdocs/website1/uploads';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {`enter code here`
    var a=file;
    createEl(a);
  });
})}
```

Comment: Do you get errors? `createEl` looks like client side code and `foldlist` like server side code.

Comment: You are mixing backend JavaScript (Node.js) with frontend JavaScript. You can't do that.

Comment: Fix minor typos, remove unneeded garbage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @str mentioned i mixed up frontend and backend javascript. Thank you all for the replies